# Solve $y^{(IV)}(x) - a^4 y(x) = \sin (ax)$ by using higher order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $y^{(iv)}(x) - a^4 y(x) = \sin (ax)$ by  using higher order differential equation

I'm stuck at what is the square root of  $D^2 = -a^2$
I m confused here ...but according to me it should be $+ia$ and $-ia$

Comment: Can you edit this to make it more readable?

Comment: @scoopfaze I do not know to edit....can u make it for me

Comment: It seems as though someone else beat me to it. :)

Comment: For future reference, try and use this to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Diwakaryadav It really isn't that hard. Notice what changes were just done for you. The starting point is to enclose math between \$\ \$

Comment: What is the square root of D^2 =-a^2 ?

Comment: If you want to solve $(D^4-a^4)y=0$ by the factorisation method you can write it as $(D-a)(D+a)(D-ia)(D-ia)y=0$ but it is easier to write down the solution as $y=Ae^{ax}+Be{-ax}+C\cos ax+E\sin ax$. Note that solving $(D\pm ia)y=0$ witll give you $Fe^{iax}$. You can combine $e^{iax},e^{-ax}$ terms to get $\sin x,\cos x£$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

When the corresponding algebraic equation in D has complex roots $ r \pm si $ ,solutions for the homogeneous differential equation are $ y=e^{rx}\cos(sx),y=e^{rx}\sin(sx) $ ,which, in this case give $ y=\cos(ax), y=\sin(ax) $
The general solution of the homogeneous equation is 
$$ y=Ae^{ax} + Be^{-ax} + C\cos(ax) + D\sin(ax)$$
Now use variation of parameters to solve the original differenial equaion.